# Does SSR break the web3 philosophy of data transparency?

Tags: web3js, dapps

I have noticed a lot of Dapps these days are server side rendered using frameworks like Next.js where data is rendered server-side on hosting providers like Vercel, Cloudflare, or self hosted servers.

Wouldn't that break the web3 transparency as Network calls between a Dapp and an RPC endpoint can't be inspected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data in Ethereum is transparent. I don't think web3 says much about *frontend* capabilities; it's not so much about frontends, but about blockchains as backend.

So the frontend can use whatever privacy means it wants, but whatever data is in Ethereum, that data is transparent and the frontend can't really do much about that "problem".

Part of the point of web3, at least in my opinion, is that anyone can create a frontend on top of some smart contract in the blockchain. And this is possible simply because the data is transparent.

Comment: Makes sense. It is down to the user to trust the responses from the Dapp and the burden of verifying the responses on the chain lies with them.